# How to execute an application from windows service

Tags: c#, windows-services, process

I have window XP 2003 server, which is placed in a room where no one can enter to logon it.

for monitoring some applications
I created a console application myServer.exe, which dont have any UI, 
I want that this application (e.g., myServer.exe) start automatically as window bootup (e.g., before window logon)

and I need to do this work using windows service.

(note: please don't suggest me any other solution, I need to use windows service to accomplish this task)

Comment: You need the console application to run as a service?

Comment: no! I need to run consol application from windows service

Comment: @zishan ahmad: Your question is confusing.  Do you have an existing Windows service that you want to modify so that it will execute your console program, or do you want to create a new Windows service?  If you want to create a new Windows service using C#, why not create a Windows service project instead of a console mode project?

Comment: do you want to create a new Windows service?
Yes! I want to create a new windo service in C#.

why not create a Windows service project instead of a console mode project?
because I am getting exception "System.UnAuthorized************

Comment: Also, by the way: there is no such operating system as "window XP 2003".  Do you mean *Microsoft Windows XP* (a desktop operating system released in 2002) or *Microsoft Windows 2003 Server* (a server operating system released in 2003)?

Comment: @zishan ahmad: Your comment makes no sense.  Which exception are you getting, exactly?  And where are you getting your exception?  Did you try creating a Windows service project and then decide to change to a console application?

Comment: Microsoft Windows 2003 Server

Answer (score 2):

The WinNT resource kit includes a utility called SRVANY.EXE that can be used to run any application as a service.  ocdecio's solution is better but if for some reason you can't redesign the app SRVANY.EXE may work.  [Here's the KB Article.](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/137890)

Comment: Your article is nice, if  it really works then it will make my life easier, let me search Instsrv.exe and srvany.exe, then I will update you

Comment: looks like someone is trying to play at school.

Answer (score 0):

You can develop Windows services directly in C#.  If you have Visual Studio Professional, there is a built-in project template for a Windows service.

MSDN has a [walkthrough of creating a service with C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zt39148a%28VS.80%29.aspx) that explains the process clearly.

If you don't have Visual Studio Professional, you can still create a service.  You'll just need to create a class that inherits from [`System.ServiceProcess.ServiceBase`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.serviceprocess.servicebase%28VS.80%29.aspx) manually.

A quick Google search turned up a couple of other links that may be helpful to you:

- http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/WindowsService.aspx
- http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/mahesh/window_service11262005045007AM/window_service.aspx